# How do I send a timed notification on React Native

Tags: push-notification, react-native

I don't need a server or anything, but basically I want to do a scheduled notification locally.

I tried using react-native-push-notification but it says I need firebase?

I just want to schedule a notification when the app is opened for a certain time

Comment: For this package you need to create firebase app in order to use it in android. Just create an app and place json file in the respected place and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use only local notification with react-native-push-notification and avoid using firebase, refer to this part of readme:[screenshot of readme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfW5B.png)

Don't worry about IOS, this library won't be used there